# DatagramSocket send blocks on Android 7.0

Tags: java, android, sockets, udp, android-7.0-nougat

I'm using a DatagramSocket in an Android app for some UDP communication with a server.  It sends packets to the server and listens for packets from the server.  This was created about four years ago and has been working fine.  A customer recently upgraded a tablet to Android 7.0 and now DatagramSocket.send(DatagramPacket) blocks indefinitely without sending anything.

I've tried the below test code to demonstrate the problem.  On all Android versions up to at least 6.0.1, the below code works as expected.  The receive method, running in a separate thread, blocks waiting for a packet.  The send method completes immediately and execution continues.  If I run this on 7.0, the send method blocks and nothing is sent.

I'm not getting any security exceptions.  I've been trying to find documentation describing a relevant change to Android or DatagramSocket but have yet to find anything.  If I don't call the receive method, the send method doesn't block.

I've tried working around this using two DatagramSocket instances: one sending, one receiving.  But the responses from the server need to come back on the same port and I don't see a way I could achieve this with two sockets.

So my questions are, why is this now happening?  Is there something new I now need to do in Android 7.0?  Or, is there another way I could work around this?

```
try {
    final DatagramSocket socket = DatagramChannel.open().socket();
    socket.bind(null);
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(new byte[100], 100, new InetSocketAddress("my.server.com", 31000));
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                DatagramPacket receivedPacket = new DatagramPacket(new byte[100], 100);
                socket.receive(receivedPacket);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    socket.send(packet);
    socket.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I don't see why it should work at all. You're binding the socket to a system-allocated port yet you're sending to port 31000. That's only going to work 1/65535 of the time, roughly speaking.

Comment: You're on pretty thin ice using `DatagramSocketChannel.socket()` in multiple threads. You may be deadlocked. Try it with `new DatagramSocket(31000)`. No reason not to, as you aren't using the Channels API in any way.

Comment: @EJP 31000 is the server port.  That's where the packet is being sent.  Not the port I'm listening on.  I might get port 12345 to bind to.  I send a packet to my.server.com:31000.  It then responds back where the packet came from, ie myipaddress:12345.  This is important because 12345 will be temporarily opened in a firewall to allow the response to come back.

Comment: @EJP Receiving on one thread and sending on another should work.  In fact, it has been for four years and through about 10 different versions of Android.  This is the first time I've seen this behaviour in all these years.

Comment: So this is only the client? So where is the server?

Comment: @EJP If I understand your question, the client is communicating with a remote server via mobile data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a bit of trial and error, I finally fixed this issue with the below code change.  I'm not sure what has changed in DatagramChannel in Android 7 but I didn't really need it anyway.

```
//final DatagramSocket socket = DatagramChannel.open().socket();
//socket.bind(null);
final DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
```

Comment: I thought it might work. I think this indicates you were deadlocked.